# Generating six pyramidical dots with Latex

Tags: unicode, fonts, symbols

I'm not sure where to put this question, but is it possible to create a graphical element with six dots in pyramid shape with Latex?

I cannot find this symbol from Unicode character blocks, so I guess next try is to make it with Latex or similar method. And if this is not working then just accepting png image...

Below symbol T3=6 is the one I'm trying to make.

[image: Pyramidical shape of dots]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with tikz. See the comments in the `\pyrdot` command definition.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\pyrdot}[1]{
    % you can tune the size of the pyramid using the scale option
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4] 
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{#1}                            % define \n, the number of rows 
        \edef\m{0}                                          % define \m, the total number of circles
        \foreach \i in {1, ..., \n} {                       % vertical loop
            \foreach \k in {1, ..., \i} {                   % horizontal loop
                \fill ($(\k,-\i)+(-.5*\i,0)$) circle (4mm); % draw the circle (size = 4mm, shifted to the left)
                \pgfmathparse{int(\m+1)}                    % increment \m
                \xdef\m{\pgfmathresult}
            }
        }
        % put the text below the pyramid
        \node[anchor=north] at (current bounding box.south) {$T_{\n}=\m$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\section{pyramidical dots}
\pyrdot{1}
\pyrdot{2}
\pyrdot{3}
\pyrdot{4}
\pyrdot{5}
\pyrdot{6}

\end{document}
```

#### References

- [A very minimal introduction to TikZ](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf)
- [TikZ & PGF at CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)

Comment: It would be helpful to explain and give a reference to tikz, plus give a small explanation of the pgfmathsetmacro, what it is doing. I tried this at overleaf.com and it was working perfectly.

Comment: @MarkokraM Please see the edits.